# Need to set default values to today for custom date column when newform.aspx loads using c#

Tags: 2007

I want to modify this codeplex solution http://datetimebyminute.codeplex.com/. Right now the custom field defaults to the date when we add the column to the list when we open the new form.aspx. I want to deafult to todays date when newform.aspx is opened.

Thanks,
Has.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the codeplex project mentioned is a custom SharePoint field control.

Answer (score 1):

datetimebyminute uses sharepoint standard DataTimeControl. DateTimeControl has property named SelectedDate. 
Below is a code to set current date in this Control

```
dtControl.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below code for SharePoint DateTime field:

DateTime Control:

```
<sharepoint:datetimecontrol ID="dtDateTime" runat="server" IsValid="true" IsRequiredField="true" ></sharepoint:datetimecontrol>
```

c# code:

```
dtDateTime.SelectedDate = System.DateTime.Now
```